# Return null from openssl_pkcs12_read function in php 8.2.4

Tags: php, laravel-8, php-8, laravel-10

I'm using the php function openssl_pkcs12_read() to read digital certificates, after updating my php to 8.2.4 it doesn't return the certificate, its return only comes null, I already enabled the openssl extension in the php.ini but still the problem persists. I tested the same function in php 8.0.1 and it worked perfectly, I already investigated and did some tests but none of them were successful, I ask for help with this problem, gentlemen.

```
$pfxContent = file_get_contents(public_path("MYCERTIFICATE.pfx"));
$password = '123456';
openssl_pkcs12_read($pfxContent, $resultCert, $password);
return $resultCert;
```

`
[php.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju01G.png)

Comment: Just a quick check is there padding around the PFX content, if you open it in a text file? you should also wrap the `openssl_pkcs12_read($pfxContent, $resultCert, $password);` in an `if` as it returns `true` or `false` based on success or failure and if `false` read the https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-error-string.php

Comment: @Barkermn01 I did the verification, I just don't know why in php 8 I can perfectly return the function and open the certificate using the function, but in php 8.2 it just returns empty and I've tested it with more than one certificate to be sure.

Comment: don't add stuff not needed to your question it's clear you have openssl extension enabled, because your not getting a call to undefined function error, my point of linking was to say if you have the If statement it will be returning false you need to read the error from the `openssl_error_string` function why does it say it's failing...

Comment: @Barkermn01 using `openssl_error_string` i've got this: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Comment: thanks for your time @Barkermn01 , I guess this will work for me.